# Need help in trying to convert number into character code

Tags: ruby, irb

I am using irb/ruby1.9.1/windows7.

I need to convert the letter "M" into character code.
I wrote the code below:

```
>M
```

I expected the result to be `77`.
But the result was `"M"`.

How can I make the letter into character code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `ord`

```
"M".ord #=> 77
```

Answer (score 1):

Try method [ord](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001177)

```
'M'.ord
```

in order to get the character code.